# Unable to test android application directly on android device instead of android simulator

Tags: android, deployment, android-emulator, titanium-mobile

hi I have developed small Android application.I want to run it on android device.I copied .apk and run on my android device it's working fine.But I don't want to every time copy .apk file when I changing my code.I just want to directly run it on my mobile device through Titanium Run --> Android Device option.I already set vender id for my device. When I tried to run my application on android device it gives me error insufficient permissions for device.I keep USB debugging enable on my device. I also tried to resolve adb issues.

```
cd android-sdk-linux-linux/tools 
./adb kill-server 
./adb start-server 
./adb devices
```

but it shows me

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I check in the DDMS but it not showing my device.It showing my simulator but not device.It shows one device icon with name as ???????? and unknown so is there any way to solve this problem.Thank you.

Comment: I know this is a stupid solution but try restarting your phone. This happened to me many times but when  I restart my phone and connect my phone to eclipse, it shows my device.

Comment: Thank you Rashmi for quick reply.I tried that solution as well but its not working for me and I am using Titanium studio not eclipse.Is there any need to start your eclipse or Titanium studio from root.I am using Ubuntu 10.4 so any drives are required?

Comment: On your device go to settings -> Application -> Development -> Check install from other sources is allowed, and 2nd check for application debugging is enabled

Comment: Thank you Vinay. In my device there is no option Check install from other sources;but I already enable application debugging option and allow mock location.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the right permission to access your device.
Try adding something like this to some file (usually 51-android.rules) in `/etc/udev/rules.d`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",SYSFS{idVendor}=="XXXX",MODE="0600",SYMLINK+="mydev-%n",OWNER="my-user-name"
```

Replace `my-user-name` and `XXXX` by the vendor id of your device which you can find using

```
   $ lsusb
```

Then restart udev

```
   $ sudo service udev restart
```

Finally, add the vendor id to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`:

```
 # USB devices
 0xXXXX
```

Comment: Hi dtmilano,Thank you for reply.I tried your solution but still it not working for me.I modified 51-android.rules file with my vendor id and add vendor id in adb_usb.ini file.But it not working.

Comment: Try to determine which part is not working: see if your device is detected, if device nodes created, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - NEW ANSWER**

I reopened this issue and sth was fishy about starting adb in root mode. So, when I plugged in Sony Z1, I run

```
mdzeko@pc ~ $ lsusb 
...
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0fce:519e Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
...
```

Automaticaly, I saw the vendor ID connected to Sony Z1. It said that `0fce` was it's vendor id. Checking google page [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds) I noticed that there is a difference between Sony and Sony Ericsson.

Checking my udev rules, it turned out that inside I had Sony vendor id (which is `054c`) instead of Sony Ericsson (which is `0fce`). Changing that code in udev made it work.

```
mdzeko@pc ~ $ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Ok, after several hours of resarch, I've come up a solution. Maybe it will apply to you aswell.

I was using Sony Z1 on Linux Mint. It gave me the same error when trying to connect it to usb. This is what I've done:

1. Add the `udev` rule by folowing VERY simple tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up)
2. run `adb kill-server`
3. There might be an option in the developer options on the device saying `Revoke USB debugging authorization...`. You can go through with that option. If there isn't an option like this, never mind, skip to the next step.
4. Run `sudo adb usb` or `sudo adb start-server`
5. If there wasn't a permission for using that device saved, You will have a dialog on the device asking you to grant the permission. Select option granting you the permission.

That's it, your device should work. If it still doesn't, commment below and I will try to see why.

P.S. I admit it is bad practice to run adb as root, but I couldn't get it to work without it. By switching to non-root adb, I got the same error again.